# How do I source a list of files from vimrc?

Tags: vim

I basically want to add something like

```
source ~/.vim/source.d/*.vim
```

to vimrc.

Is it possible to loop over a set of globbed files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `:runtime!` command (including the `!`).

```
:runtime! source.d/*.vim
```

This is how the plugin folder is loaded.

Answer (score 4):

Why don't you put them into your ~/.vim/plugin/ directory?
It will get the job done, and transparently furthermore.

Comment: Somehow this did not work properly when loading .py files from the command line: the `call matchadd()` (and probably everything else was not properly setup): from turning on "-verbose" it looked like it did not trigger `autocmd` for *.py, but for *.

Comment: python specific configuration shall not go into plain plugins, but into ftplugins.

Answer (score 0):

Got the following answer on #vim:

```
exe join(map(split(glob("~/.vim/source.d/*.vim"), "\n"), '"source " . v:val'), "\n")
```

Comment: `split(glob(...))` without `"\n"` works just fine, if it is not supposed to handle filenames with spaces. If it is then you miss escaping some characters (starting with space).